# Parallax effect scrolling of multiple images

Tags: android, parallax, effect

I'm trying to get a use multiple image in a live wallpaper to behave like a regular wallpaper with regard to scrolling when the user rotate home screens. I know the method required for this is onOffsetsChanged, but I can't seem to get it working.

Does anyone have advice or a code snippet to get this working?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question to share the code that you tried so far, along with the issues you encountered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can either do it by creating Class which extends WallpaperService and use TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor for parallax. I have created a demo project of Parallax wallpaper. [Click Here](https://github.com/salmankhalid876/MyParallax)